# How to speed up gulp compilation on M1 chip?

Tags: gulp, apple-m1

Recently, i got a task to work on a bunch of code that over 10 years old.And our development machine uses Apple M1 chip.The front-end part has all kinds of technologies, even angular 1.x.x! These code can only be successfully compiled under node v6.2.2 and gulp v3.9.1, but M1 run "gulp" takes 50 minutes each time. If i upgrade node and gulp, new errors will be generated.Our new function is coded by react 18, i'm terrified of future compile times.Is there any good solution to speed up gulp compilation?(The project also doesn't use browseify, watchify)

Comment: It's a valid question, but from the experience I find it unlikely anyone is going to maintain or support or be able to help with such old software.